# Resizing every VARCHAR column in database table - Oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle

I have at least 65 `VARCHAR` columns in Table `A` that I would have to resize from `X bytes` to `X char`. I was hoping to find a simpler way than issue `ALTER TABLE A MODIFY..` command 65 times.

Can anyone please help me out how I can do this is a faster way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write a bit of dynamic SQL.  Assuming that the table is in the current schema

```
DECLARE
  l_sql_stmt VARCHAR2(1000);
BEGIN
  FOR t IN (SELECT * FROM user_tab_cols WHERE table_name = 'A')
  LOOP
    l_sql_stmt := 'ALTER TABLE ' || t.table_name || ' MODIFY (' || 
                     t.column_name || ' varchar2(' || t.char_length || ' char))';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_sql_stmt;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Which you can see working below

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  create table foo(
  2    col1 varchar2(10 byte),
  3    col2 varchar2(20 byte)
  4* )
SQL> /

Table created.

DECLARE
  l_sql_stmt VARCHAR2(1000);
BEGIN
  FOR t IN (SELECT * FROM user_tab_cols WHERE table_name = 'FOO')
  LOOP
    l_sql_stmt := 'ALTER TABLE foo MODIFY (' || 
                     t.column_name || ' varchar2(' || t.char_length || ' char))';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_sql_stmt;
  END LOOP;
END;


SQL> desc foo;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 COL1                                               VARCHAR2(10 CHAR)
 COL2                                               VARCHAR2(20 CHAR)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try something ugly like that

```
 select 'ALTER TABLE '||table_name|
        ' MODIFY ('||column_name||' VARCHAR2('||char_length||' char));'
   from all_tab_cols
   where table_name='A' and
         datatype like 'VARCHAR2%';
```

copy the result grid and paste it in and run it in your prefered sql editor

Comment: I do like this technique as it works in all DBMSes and doesn't rely on procedural extensions specific to each. Often this can be combined with some spooling functionality to create a new SQL script that can then be executed.

Answer (score 2):

Justin's answer is partly incorrect - in fact grokster's is better - spot the difference:

**Justin:**

```
  FOR t IN (SELECT * FROM user_tab_cols WHERE table_name = 'A')
```

**Grokster:**

```
FOR x IN (SELECT * FROM user_tab_cols WHERE table_name = 'A' AND datatype LIKE 'VARCHAR%')
```

Notice that Grokster checks the datatype correctly instead of trying to convert all of the columns to varchar2!

Answer (score 1):

```
BEGIN
    FOR x IN (SELECT * FROM user_tab_cols WHERE table_name = 'A' AND datatype LIKE 'VARCHAR%')
    LOOP
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE '||x.table_name||' MODIFY '||x.column_name ||' VARCHAR2('||x.char_length||' CHAR)';
    END LOOP; 
END;
/
```

Comment: How is this significantly different to Justin's accepted answer of two years ago?

Comment: It's not. I'm just showing that the same result can be achieved with less code. It's a refinement if you will.